# How to edit specific jenkins jobs using groovy script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I want to stop some of my jenkins jobs not to run in parallel. To accomplish that i am adding below code in my scripted pipeline. But, I have some 100 jenkins jobs in which i want to add below lines in bulk, how can i do it using groovy script ? Doing it manually will take a lot of time and i want to avoid that.

```
properties([
 disableConcurrentBuilds()
])
```

Comment: not sure what you are trying to accomplish , can you explain a little more?

Comment: Pipeline jobs? JobDSL jobs? Freestyle jobs? What have you tried? What was the result?